# Splitting in F8 Confusion

Tags: field-theory

I am so confused about the following question:

Consider the field F8 = F2[θ]/($0^3$ + θ + 1). Check that the
polynomial $x^3$ + x + 1 splits in this field as
$x^3$ + x + 1 = (x + θ)(x + $θ^2$
)(x + $θ^2$ + θ).
Now take the other degree three irreducible polynomial x
3 + x
2 + 1 over F2.
Show that it also splits in F8 and find its roots in F8.

First, what is the θ? Why are θ and x different variables? So is θ then a constant in F8?

For $x^3+x^2+1$, I think we would do $x^3$ = -x - 1 = x + 1, so $x^3 + x^2 + 1$ = $x^2$ + x = x(x+1) with roots 0 and 1. But I'm not sure if this is right since it doesn't use $\theta$.

I'm really just confused about what the $\theta$ represents.

Comment: $\theta$ is an element of $\mathbb F_8$ satisfying $\theta^3+\theta+1=0$

Comment: Please consider enclosing entire expressions in dollar signs, rather than just a term here and there. $x^3+x+1$ (given by `$x^3+x+1$`) looks much better than $x^3$ + x + 1 (given by `$x^3$ + x + 1`).

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yeah, I know that. But I really don't get it, what is the difference between this and the field $F2[x]/(x^3 + x + 1$)? I'd think they are the same because it's just different variable names but apparently not? Does $x^3 + x^2 + 1 = 0$ here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb F_8$ has six elements in addition to $0$ and $1$. They each need a name. Here they have chosen to use $\theta$ to construct these names. We get that $\theta$ is an element of $\Bbb F_8$. Also, the two expressions $\theta^3+\theta + 1$ and $0$ denote the exact same element of $\Bbb F_8$.

Then, *on top of this*, we are making polynomials with elements of $\Bbb F_8$ as coefficients. These polynomials need a variable, here they have chosen $x$ as the name of that variable. Such a polynomial could look like
$$
\theta^2x^5 + (\theta + 1)x^4 + (\theta^2+1)x^3 + x^2 + (\theta^2 + \theta).
$$
This is a fifth degree polynomial, with a variety of coefficients from $\Bbb F_8$.

We have that $x^3+x+1$ is a third-degree polynomial with coefficients from $\Bbb F_8$ (the coefficients all happen to be $0$ and $1$). And $\theta$ is one of its roots. As such, the linear polynomial $x+\theta$ (with constant term $\theta$) is a factor of $x^3+x+1$.

Yes, the concrete construction of $\Bbb F_8$ is as a quotient of the polynomial ring $\Bbb F_2[\theta]$, so technically the elements of $\Bbb F_8$ are equivalence classes of polynomials over $\Bbb F_2$ in the variable $\theta$. And these equivalence classes are then used as the coefficients in a new polynomial ring in the variable $x$. Following along here does take a little getting used to.

There is no big reason to use $\theta$ to make the names of elements in $\Bbb F_8$. We could just as well have used $x$, and said that $\Bbb F_8 = \Bbb F_2[x]/(x^3+x+1)$. However, we would still need a variable name for the polynomials with $\Bbb F_8$-coefficients, and you can't use $x$ for both; confusion would be unavoidable, even for seasoned algebraists. The authors of your problem wanted the polynomial variable to be called $x$, and they wanted to use $\theta$ to name the elements of $\Bbb F_8$.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it; this makes a lot of sense!